# Get all data in one row without repetition using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, repeat

guys! I want to know how can I get all data in a row without repetition.

For example, this is my row in a table

```
| category |
+----------+
|   HTML   |
|   HTML   |
|   HTML   |
|   CSS    |
|    JS    |
|    JS    |
```

Okay, so for example, I want to echo all category with repetition so the result must be like this

```
| HTML |
| CSS  |
|  JS  |
```

Instead of...

```
| HTML |
| HTML |
| HTML |
| CSS  |
|  JS  |
|  JS  |
```

How can I do that in a query? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT category
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY category
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT category
FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT columnName FROM t1`